# Search Bar fires but no changes take effect - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I'm trying to do a search filter using Ant.Design Search component and I followed their documentation carefully but It fires and the the searchQuery state changes but nothing happens.

Also in my console I can see that it fires twice so it gets logged 2 times and I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Layout, Loading } from "../components";
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import { set } from "react-ga";
// import config from '../config.json';

const { Search } = Input;

const Overview = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
    },
    {
      title: "Type",
      dataIndex: "username",
      key: "username",
    },
    {
      title: "Balance",
      dataIndex: "phone",
      key: "phone",
    },
    {
      title: "Status",
      dataIndex: "website",
      key: "website",
    },
    {
      title: "",
      dataIndex: "",
      key: "website",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    async function callApi() {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
      const devices = response.data;
      setDevices(devices);
      // const response = await axios.get(`${config.serverAPI}/devices`);
      // const devices = response?.data?.status === 'success' && response?.data?.devices;
      // console.log("Devices", devices);

      await localStorage.setItem("devices", JSON.stringify(devices));
      setLoading(false);
    }
    callApi();
  }, [searchQuery]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="overview-page-wrapper">
        {loading ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Search
              placeholder="Search for devices"
              value={searchQuery}
              onChange={(e) => {
                const currSearchValue = e.target.value;
                setSearchQuery(currSearchValue);
                const filteredDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.name.toLowerCase().includes(currSearchValue));
                setDevices(filteredDevices);
              }}
            />
            {console.log(searchQuery)}
            <div>
              <Table columns={columns} dataSource={devices} />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Overview;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to modify your code as less as possible. I would sagest 3 changes

1 - Remove the `searchQuery` dependency from the first Effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function callApi() {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
      const devices = response.data;
      setDevices(devices);
      // const response = await axios.get(`${config.serverAPI}/devices`);
      // const devices = response?.data?.status === 'success' && response?.data?.devices;
      // console.log("Devices", devices);

      await localStorage.setItem("devices", JSON.stringify(devices));
      setLoading(false);
    }
    callApi();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

2 - Add `filterdDevices` state and also an Effect

```
const [filterdDevices, setFilteredDevices] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = devices.filter(device =>
      device.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery)
    );
    setFilteredDevices(filtered);
}, [searchQuery, devices]);
```

3 - Simplify `onChange` on Select component

```
<Search
    placeholder="Search for devices"
    value={searchQuery}
    onChange={e => {
      const currSearchValue = e.target.value;
      setSearchQuery(currSearchValue);
    }}
/>
```